# Zero set of the Fourier transform of a singular measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Denote by $M_{sc}(\mathbb{R})$ the set of all continuous singular probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Is there $\mu\in M_{sc}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$\lambda(\{x:\int\limits_\mathbb{R} e^{itx}d\mu(t)=0\})>0$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure?

It is easy to give examples of Fourier transform of absolutely continouos and discrete measures with such property. For example, $(1-|x|)_+$ and its periodic extension from $[-h,h]$, where $h>1$. But I don't know how to approach this question in case of continuous singular measures.

Partial answer:

Let $s$ be a Fourier transform of continuous singular probability measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{T}$, i.e.
$s(n):=\int\limits_\mathbb{T}e^{int}d\nu(t)$ such that $0<\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} |s(n)|<1$ and let $f$ be a compactly supported characteristic function, $supp f\subset[-1,1]$. Let $h>1$. Consider the function
$$
F(x):=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}s(n)f(x-2nh),\ x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
It's known, that $F$ is a characteristic function (see W. Feller An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Application, vol. 2, Ch. XIX, Problem 15--16).  So it is sufficient to show that a measure which corresponds to $F$ contains a continuous singular component.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: How do you do this for a discrete measure? From this, one could maybe construct a continuous singular measure which fulfills your property.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It gave me an idea to consider an infinite sum of translations of compactly supported functions.